# Possible to compensate width of image and center horizontal?

Tags: css

I have a div with an image inside. I wonder if it possible to place this div 50% horizontal and compansate for half of the image. When I use 50%, the image isn't centered, because of the width of the image. I could use 49% and it looks OK on bigger screen, but on a mobile screen, it's not OK. The image is 100px wide.

Is there a way to solve this?

HTML

```
<div class="fullscreen-arrow"><img src="wimages/arrow.png" alt="button"></div>
```

CSS

```
.fullscreen-arrow {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common trick is to use a negative margin that's half as wide (or high) as your image:

```
.fullscreen-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;

  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

This assumes that your image is 50 pixels high and 100 pixels wide (and that you know the size of your image beforehand).

[Demo (jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/hd2215o4/)